# Floating button with link to last viewed page

Tags: css, button, navigation, sticky, squarespace

I would like to add a button that travels with the scroll of the user, or is stuck to the bottom of the window.

I have pages of instructions (ex. [/georgia-insurance-license](https://staterequirement.com/georgia-insurance-license)) that have internal links to other posts (ex. [How to Pass the Insurance Exam](https://www.staterequirement.com/free-tools-posts/how-to-pass-the-insurance-exam)).

Instead of the user having to press the back button on the browser, or navigating the two steps to their state page from navigation, it would be better if there were a one button click that linked them back to the state page that they came from.

It would also be great if it would play nice with mobile.

If you have a sticky button idea, please let me know!

Also, I'm on SquareSpace, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you'll want to use 'fixed' positioning.

markup

```
<button class='special-button'>special button</button>
```

styles

```
.special-button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/1u4y2csj/

Comment: Cool, that solves the button position problem.  Do you have any thoughts on how to get the button to link back to the "state page"?

Also, it's possible that they could navigate to the "How to pass the exam" page from a "non-state" page. 
Is there a way to save a cookie to the user for the duration of the visit that links that person to the state that they have selected first?

Comment: You can create a link to the 'list' page with a normal `<a href='whatever-destination>state list</a>` ~ and the same for how to pass the exam - and any and all pages. I'm not sure if links in squarespace are unique - or if you are just new to HTML. There ARE ways to create a cookie to show their chosen state etc - but StackOverflow is not for groups of problems - and you haven't really shown any work so far. I recommend learning about 'html links' 'css positioning' and 'cookies' on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fixed` property so it travels as it scrolls. 
and add `onclick="history.back(-1)` to go back one page.

```css
.backBtn {
  position: fixed;
  left: 40%;
  top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button class='backBtn' onclick="history.back(-1)">GO BACK! </button>
```